# OTP like Identity

Tags: encryption, data-privacy, identity-based-encryption

I am a developer with very little experience on the crypto part,
and I'm looking for a secure solution (OTP Like) for identifying between client (browser) and server.

this is what i need:

Web Page at 10.00 AM generate a randomly id based on a secret key

User A

**10.00 AM** `258e461ba8b7b66a02cf17dfe60f465c103c742e570f492a31931424f38e0d5c`

**10.15 AM** `21309341c1278cbd4670668a81144c06ea27bfdbdf44f1ee0c28a2a7f9a17d34`

**10.30 AM** `34b3b35600af44544c53b05d8d44357774d1f03bff40a6ea81ea196925d71357`

...

every 15 min the script generate a new id

when the client send the generated secret id to the server the server with the same secret key it must be able to identify the A user

what algorithm or technique can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) or MAC. If you compute the MAC of the time and date with the shared secret key, you should be assured that it is only computable by people who know the key. ETA: [Mikero](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/192/mikero) points out that the [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password) standard uses this approach for your problem.

If you want something truly analogous to the One-Time Pad you should use a [One-Time MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code#One-time_MAC) such as the Carter-Wegman construction.

Comment: There is a standard for this functionality called [TOTP (Time-based one-time passwords)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password).

Comment: @Mikero Excellent observation. With your permission, I shall add it to the answer.

Comment: Of course, go ahead!